# Using methods inside loop invariants in Dafny

Tags: dafny, loop-invariant

I'm trying to prove the simple `gcd` algorithm in Dafny, so I wrote the following, but it seems I can not use the method `divides` inside the loop invariants:

```
method divides(d: int, x: int) returns (result: bool)
    requires d > 0
    requires x > 0
    ensures (result == true ) ==> (exists q : int :: (d * q == x))
    ensures (result == false) ==> (forall q : int :: (d * q != x))
{
    // code omitted
}

method gcd(a: int, b: int) returns (result: int)
    requires a > 0
    requires b > 0
    ensures (forall d : int :: ((exists q1 : int :: q1 * d == a) && (exists q2 :: (q2 * d == b))) ==>
                 (exists q3 : int :: (q3 * d == result)))
{
    var x := a;
    var y := b;
    var fuel := a+b;
    while ((x != y) && (fuel > 0))
        decreases fuel
        invariant x > 0
        invariant y > 0
        invariant (forall d : int :: (divides(d,x) && divides(d,y)) ==> (divides(d,a) && divides(d,b)))
    {
        // code omitted
    }
    return x;
}
```

Is there anyway to use a `divides` method/function/macro inside invariants?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike methods, functions can appear in expressions. You can create a function:

```
function div(d: int, x: int): bool
{
    if (d != 0 && x % d == 0) then true else false
}
```

Then in your method `divides`,  you can have

```
ensures result == div(d,x)
```

and in your method `gcd` you can use the function `div` in your invariant.

Note, from the Dafny guide: One caveat of functions is that not only can they appear in annotations, they can only appear in annotations. Functions are never part of the final compiled program, they are just tools to help us verify our code.